# Weird behaviour in VB 2005 IDE with SP 2

Tags: vb.net, .net-2.0

I am having a strange behaviour in VB 2005. I hit F5 to run my asp.net app in debug mode, step through the code lines, stop the app running (before the end) and then when I hit F5, its starts back from where it previously stopped (as opposed to starting from the begining of the app).

Any idea what could be causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wonder if Visual Studio isn't correctly detaching from your running ASP.NET process.

I'm not sure how you're 'stopping the app', but try doing so by clicking the 'Debug' menu and selecting 'Terminate All.'

If this does the trick for you, you can make the command a little more accessible by adding it to your toolbar (right click the VS toolbar, select 'Customize...', select the Commands tab and select Category = Debug and then drag the 'Terminate All' command to one of your toolbars).

Comment: I am stopping the app by clicking the square button "stop debugging" icon on the toolbar. But I wil try out you suggestion. Thanks.